# Include more than one snakefile

Tags: snakemake

I would like to include more than one snakefile in the main Snakemake.

```
 prefixed = [filename for filename in os.listdir('.') if filename.startswith("Snakefile.")]
 include: ",".join(prefixed)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work.

Is there is build in method? Or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the way

```
for f in prefixed:
    include: f
```